# Получить картинку с google maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Хочу сделать такое:

1. Пользователь открывает окошко
2. Выбирает место на карте
3. Нажимает Отправить
4. На сервер отправляется картинка, та которую видел пользователь на
       картах (в том же масштабе и др.)

Карту загружаю в `iframe` так вот

```
<iframe name="mapframe" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=ru&amp;geocode=&amp;q=&amp;aq=&amp;sll=0&amp;sspn=0&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;z=12&amp;ll=0&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, может быть это приблизит вас к истине http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737134/html2canvas-no-screenshot-for-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае проще на сервер отправлять координаты и уровень zoom-a, а затем уже при помощи [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) запрашивать статическую картинку для выбранной пользователем области.

Вариант с отрисовкой скриншота страницы в canvas, на который указал Александр в комментариях, не пройдет из-за ограничений безопасности (cross origin).